# Dummy variables-Regression

Tags: logistic

I am running a logistics regression where I have many covariates that I am controlling for. Should I be using dummy variables for those covariates? I am wondering since I am not really interested in looking at the effect of those covariates and am just interested in controlling them. My covariates are gender, race , education, age, smoking and diabetes. Will using dummies or not using them change my output?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the other option you are considering? If you aren't going to use a dummy variable for gender, what would you use?

Comment: Of course it will change the output. You will see more rows with coefficient estimates. I am pretty sure that's not the answer to the question you had in mind, but it is an answer to THE question that you DID ask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if they are correlated with your X and Y variables, they will bias your estimate if omitted.

One noteworthy time you should avoid dummy variables in the logistic case is if you are using panel data appraches, in these cases the simple inclusion of dummy variables for each individual and time will not inherently be valid in the case of many individuals. But that is the only time this comes to mind.

Comment: This is a rather sparse answer. Can you flesh it out more?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not plan to omit them from my model but am unsure of whether to use them as dummies or just otherwise.